# Micro-controller as a load

Tags: microcontroller, load

For my power-supply micro-controller is a load. How does this load behave like? is it resistive or capacitive or inductive load?

Comment: Resistive is probably closest to reality, but it changes quickly with clock, with different instructions being executed, with peripherals being enabled, with output pins loaded ... etc. Asking this question gives me a feeling you are trying to cut corners where you really shouldn't. The power supply is the most important part of your project, without a good PSU your entire project can fail to work. Give us more details on what you are trying to do and how you consider to implement that. With that information people can give you hints/tips how to improve if needed.

Comment: give more details..Micro controllers always won't take current in same way...

Comment: In our project we are trying to provide power supply through a  magnetic latching relay. the load is a micro-controller. the ratings of relay is based on what kind of load is being used.hence i asked the question.

Comment: The rating of the relay is probably far above what you require for the micro controller in any case, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

A microcontroller's "load" varies depending on what you're doing on it. This means that if you're taking it as a resistive load. The resistance changes as the power it draws changes. This is a very hard question to answer, however I would recommend going to the specific MCU data sheet, finding it's maximum power consumption and also find the block diagram and base the load and impedance on the first block relating the the power input

Answer (score 0):

A direct voltage source always thinks it's supplying a purely resistive load. That load may change, e.g. when charging a capacitor, but in this case it would see a resistance that varied from very small to infinite as the capacitor charges. For an inductive load, it would see an initial open circuit, then a resistance that decreased to the resistance of the windings as the transient proceeds